# SQL Server equivalent of MySQL Dump to produce insert statements for all data in a table

Tags: sql-server

I have an application that uses a SQL Server database with several instances of the database...test, prod, etc... I am making some application changes and one of the changes involves changing a column from a nvarchar(max) to a nvarchar(200) so that I can add a unique constraint on it. SQL Server tells me that this requires dropping the table and recreating it.

I want to put together a script that will do the table drop, recreate it with the new schema, and then reinsert the data that was there previously all in one go, if possible, just to keep things simple for use when I migrate this change to production.

There is probably a good SQL Server way to do this but I'm just not aware of it. If I was using Mysql I would mysqldump the table and its contents,  and use that as my script for applying that change to production. I can't find any export functionality in SQL server that will give me a text file consisting of inserts for all data in a table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use SQL Server's Generate Scripts command

- right click on the database; Tasks -> Generate Scripts
- select your tables, click Next
- click the Advanced button
- find Types of data to script - choose Schema and Data.
- you can then choose to save to file, or put in new query window.
- results in `INSERT` statements for all table data selected in bullet 2.

[image: SQL Server Generate Scripts Data]

Comment: Thank you. I don't know how I missed that. I guess I was expecting to be able to right click  the table and have it offer me options for exporting that table's data.

Answer (score 2):

No need to script

here are two ways

1 use `alter table ....alter column.....`

example..you have to do 1 column at a time

```
create table Test(SomeColumn nvarchar(max))
go

alter table Test alter column SomeColumn nvarchar(200)
go
```

2 dump into a new table while converting the column

```
select <columns except for the columns you want to change>, 
    convert(nvarchar(200),YourColumn) as YourColumn
into SomeNewTable
 from OldTable
```

drop old table

rename this table to the same table as the old table

```
EXEC sp_rename 'SomeNewTable', 'OldTable';
```

Now add your index