# SQL Server 2005, export table into inserts query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, insert, dump

I'm not able to find in SQL Server 2005 the utility that phpmyadmin has for exporting tables.

I need a way to dump all info a table contains in a query with all the instert into in it.

How can I do that with SQL Server 2005?

Comment: Check this link, hope it will help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225923/sql-server-equivalent-of-mysql-dump-to-produce-insert-statements-for-all-data-in

Comment: and also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85186/mysqldump-equivalent-for-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Database publishing wizard` tool you can find it under the SQL Server install directory